# Remote validation causes double submit

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a problem with remote validation causing a form to submit twice (and enter the success/error handler twice). The original is an ASP.NET MVC application with unobtrusive validation and jQuery Form for AJAX submitting, but I've been able to reduce to the following:

**remote.json**

> "true"

**test.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<title>test</title>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="foo" type="text" value="foo">
    <br>
    <input name="bar" type="text" value="bar">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script>
    $("form").validate(
    {
        rules:
        {
            foo: { remote: { url: "remote.json" } },
            bar: { required: true }
        }
    });

    $("form").on("submit", function ()
    {
        console.log("entering the submit handler");

        if ($(this).valid())
        {
            console.log("form is valid");
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("form is invalid");
        }

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

When the remote validation returns `"true"`, this is the console output:

> GET `http://localhost/validation/remote.json?foo=foo` 200 OK
>   entering the submit handler
>   form is valid
>   entering the submit handler
>   form is valid

When the remote validation returns `"false"`, this is the console output:

> GET `http://localhost/validation/remote.json?foo=foo` 200 OK
>   entering the submit handler
>   form is valid

Am I doing something wrong in my submit handler? It works fine for all other forms (dozens of them). Or is this yet another bug in the library (if so, is there a workaround)?

Comment: Are you double clicking ?

Comment: @user1281385 No. I've tried both clicking and pressing enter. The double submit is 100% reproducible when using remote validation. When using any other kind of validation (like `required`), it is 100% not reproducible.

Answer (score 3):

Your external submit handler is going to fire whether the form is valid or not and your `return false` is also going to block the regular submit of the form, thereby interfering with the normal operation of the plugin.

That's why the developer has provided special callback handlers that automatically capture the submit event upon click.

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        foo: {
            remote: { 
                url: "remote.json"
            } 
        },
        bar: { 
            required: true 
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // form is valid - do stuff, ajax?
        return false; // block the default form action if using ajax
    },
    invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {
        // form is invalid - do stuff
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/MwXN7/**

See documentation: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

If you must use a handler external to the callback functions provided by the plugin, the `click` handler works best in this regard...

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // block the default submit
    if ($('form').valid()) {
        console.log("form is valid");
        $('#myform').submit(); // now submit the form
    } else {
        console.log("form is invalid");
    }
});
```

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/MwXN7/1/**

Although, as you can see by comparing the two demos, the second uses a lot of external code to duplicate what's already handled automatically by the plugin.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'll take a closer look tomorrow. This took us by surprise since we had no issues for so long, it only appeared when adding remote validation.

Answer (score 0):

I had de same problem and I fixed it triggering the remote validation through blur event on load.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=foo]").blur();
});
```

Comment: This works for me $("input[name=foo]").focus().blur();